# Android app updating

Tags: android, updates

I have an android app in the play store. If I upload a new apk through the developer console, does all the users who have downloaded the current version of the app get notified of the new update automatically? Or is this something, I should include in my code or is it done by Google?

Comment: This open source GitHub project (MAHAndroidUpdater)is completely providing update functionality. Try it, Very simple. https://github.com/hummatli/MAHAndroidUpdater

Answer (score 2):

The update notification is provided by the android market.

It is granular enough that if you changed something that makes this new update not available anymore for older version(say 2.1) then only the people with device capable of using your new update will be notified.

Further more, if the end user has checked the automatic box for your update, they won't have to do a thing to get the new version. It will be automatically updated for them and they will get a notification about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is done automatically, no need to add anything in code. It may take a couple of hours for the PlayStore to show your update, though.

Sometimes, devices take some time to notice the update, but it should show up after 6 hours or so.

Answer (score 0):

Play Store app has settings for user to be notified of updates for new app. 
However this is mostly a grouped notification with the play store icon and text such as "

> Updates are available for installed applications

If you want you can detect new version inside the app and show custom notification but this would require your app to be launched first.

You can use this library to check for updates
https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker

Comment: or you can even run a service every day or so to check if your app has any update and issue a notification accordingly